# R -- make a prediction based upon multiple fields (factors), but not the entire data frame

Tags: r, random-forest

Ok, I have a data frame with 250 observations of 9 variables. For simplicity, let's just label them A - I

I've done all the standard stuff (converting things to int or factor, creating the data partition, test and train sets, etc).

What I want to do is use columns A and B, and predict column E. I don't want to use the entire set of nine columns, just these three when I make my prediction.

I tried only using the limited columns in the prediction, like this:

```
myPred <- predict(rfModel, newdata=myData)
```

where rfModel is my model, and myData only contains the two fields I want to use, as a dataframe. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Error in predict.randomForest(rfModel, newdata = myData) : 
>     variables in the training data missing in newdata

Honestly, I'm very new to R, and I'm not even sure this is feasible. I think the data that I'm collecting (the nine fields) are important to use for "training", but I can't figure out how to make a prediction using just the "resultant" field (in this case field E) and the other two fields (A and B), and keeping the other important data.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. I can post some of the code if necessary.

I'm just trying to learn more about things like this.

Comment: If you want to predict using only `A` and `B`, then I think perhaps your model should be built using only these two predictors.  Can you elaborate on why you want to train on `A` through `I` but then predict using only `A` and `B` ?

Comment: Could you please show us the statement you used to build your model?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm experimenting with sports and predicting winners. A and B are the teams that would go head-to-head, the rest are stats.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So basically what I want is to use set up something like winner (as 0/1) = "Home" vs "Visitor". 0 means the visitor won, 1 means the home team won. So my prediction should return a 1 or a 0, depending on the model.

Answer (score 0):

A assume you used random forest method:

```
library(randomForest)
model <- randomForest(E ~ A+ B - c(C,D,F,G,H,I), data = train) 
pred <- predict(model, newdata = test)
```

As you can see in this example only A and B column would be taken to build a model, others are removed from model building (however not removed from the dataset). If you want to include all of them use (E~ .). It also means that if you build your model based on all column you need to have those columns in test set too, predict won't work without them. If the test data have only A and B column the model has to be build based on them.

Hope it helped

Comment: I tried this solution, but it keeps telling me that I am missing a column, even though I have included them all.

Comment: Check then if columns have the exact the same names and types as to be recognized as the same one, maybe that is the problem

Comment: I checked, and they do seem to all have the same names and types.

Comment: Hi, do not have aby other idea :( Error was clearly saying that new data you want to use your model to predict don't have variables that was building that model

Comment: I think part of the problem is I misunderstood part of the example I was using. I left out the wrong column when I was doing my randomForest. Instead of excluding the second column, I was excluding the first column. The next time I try it, I will exclude the correct column and report back.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, perhaps you should be building your model using only the `A` and `B` columns.  If you can't/don't want to do this, then one workaround perhaps would be to simply use the median values for the other columns when calling `predict`.  Something like this:

```
myData <- cbind(data[, c("A", "B)], median(data$C), median(data$D), median(data$E),
                median(data$F), median(data$G), median(data$H), median(data$I))
myPred <- predict(rfModel, newdata=myData)
```

This would allow you to use your current model, built with 9 predictors.  Of course, you would be assuming average behavior for all predictors except for `A` and `B`, which might not behave too differently from a model built solely on `A` and `B`.

Comment: I am going to try your solution. I will report back with the results when I do.

Comment: I tried this solution, and I got an error stating that object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.